# Nodejs api not accepting the POST method, error 405

Tags: node.js, express, nginx-reverse-proxy

I already search for existing question, but none of them worked for me.

I've simple nodejs methods, on my localhosts they work fine, but when I hosted them on a server (nginx), my post method gives error of 405 (not allowed), even though I've allowed CORS
Here is my server file

```
var http = require('http');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var cors = require('cors')
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
var DB = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/ClientApp';
app.use(express.json());
const clientRoutes = require('./client');
const authRoutes = require('./auth');

app.get('/api/status', (request, response) => {
    // console.log(request.body);
    response.json({ status: ' Server Running' });
});
app.use('/', clientRoutes);
app.use('/', authRoutes);
app.listen(3000, (resp) => {
    console.log('server listening at port number: ', 3000);
});
```

and here is the route that is not working

```
app.post('/api/register', (request, response) => {
    console.log('Request body: ', request.body);
    mongo.connect(DB, (error, client) => {
        console.log('Connect to Database successfully');
        const connectedDb = client.db('ClientApp');
        data = request.body;
        if (data.username) {
            connectedDb.collection('Users').insertOne(data, (error) => {
                if (error)
                    console.log('Error occured while registration')
                else {
                    response.status(200).send({ status: 'Response Received Successfully', code: 200 })
                    console.log('User registered successfully!');
                }
            })
        } else {
            response.status(204).send({ status: 'Please include the user details', code: 204 })
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: You are hard coded to listen on port `3000`, is this how you have your NGINX configuration set up as well?

Comment: so on what port or IP address should I listen ?
In my nginx I'm just using reverse proxy,

Comment: That really depends on how it is configured. It is rare that the reverse proxy will pass traffic on the same port it came in on. It is common that you use the the environment variable PORT to set the apps port, so `app.listen(3000, (resp) => {` becomes `app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, (resp) => {`. Again all of this depends on how the reverse proxy and system is configured.

Answer (score 1):

I see you have your app's listening port set to `3000`. You will need to verify in the `nginx.conf` file that is the port the traffic is being set to from the reverse proxy. Depending on how things are setup, there may be an environment variable set indicating which port the app should listen to. This variable is commonly called `PORT`.

If the `PORT` environment variable is being set you can change your code like so:

```js
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, (resp) => {
    console.log('server listening at port number: ', 3000);
});
```

In case you're not aware, using `process.env.PORT || 3000` will use the value `process.env.PORT` if it is set. If it is falsy then `3000` will be used.

For `NGINX` have a look at the `nginx.conf` at the `server` entries to determine how the reverse proxy is sending traffic to backend apps.